# Href's has ID's to scroll to Div's but it's jumping and skipping some of the section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

This project is a website that has all of its pages /sections in one page. I have assigned ID's to each section (sectio1, section2, section3 etc..), and I have also assiged these section in the top navigation href's for example `<a href="**#section2**">**About us**</a>`. So when you click on About us from the top navigation it will take you to the Div that have an ID of `#section2`.

I got this part right, however I am experiencing few problems - I have researched but I don't think I know the actually keywords for it to find the solution! so I found nothing, any help will be much appreciated.

1) When clicking on the button from the menu it JUMP to the specified section but it actually does NOT jump to the very top of the section - it like scroll down to 100px down?! why does it do that...

2) Is there anyway to make it SCROLL smoothly and no JUMP?

3) Is there an easy way to make the buttons have the class .active when they are clicked and scrolled to their section?

**Here a the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nd8MN/3/ and here is the HTML & CSS;**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Spacehopper Design</title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=10.0, initial-scale=1.0" />      

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/elements/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width : 1030px)" href="assets/css/tablets-landscape.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width : 770px)" href="assets/css/tablets-portrait.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width : 500px)" href="assets/css/phone.css"/>             
    <!--Libraries-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libraries/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header><!--Header-->
        <div id="headerWrapper">
            <div id="headerContent">

                <div id="headerLogo">
                    <a href="index.php"><img alt="Logo" src="assets/elements/logo.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <nav><ul id="mainMenu"><!--Main Menu-->
                    <li><a class="active" href="#section1">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section2">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section3">Endorsements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section4">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section5">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul></nav>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="Page"><!--Website Content-->       

        <div id="secondHeader">
            <a class="secondHeader-menuButton" href="#">Menu</a>
            <p id="logo-smallScreen">Spacehopper Design</p>
        </div>

        <div id="section1" class="wrapperA"><!--Page Content-->
            <div id="home-sectionA" class="content" >
                <img src="assets/elements/home-sectionA-background.png">
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div id="section2" class="wrapperB"><!--Page Content-->
            <div id="home-sectionB" class="content" >
                <img src="assets/elements/home-sectionB-background.png">
                <div id="home-sectionB-textbox1">
                    <h3>...three words that epitomise Spacehopper Design​​​​.</h3><br>
                    <p>We strongly believe that everything begins with an idea, and that there is a big idea hidden in all of us.</p>
                    <p>You may have that Eureka moment, but are unsure how to develop this idea further from an upbeat, design perspective.</p>
                    <p>This is where Spacehopper Design can help. We are a fast, focused and forward-thinking conceptual agency who promise to find an intuitive solution to your design needs. And of course, we’ll have fun doing so.</p>
                    <p>With our wealth of experience in editorial design, print design and branding, we also have a deep knowledge of understanding our target audience requirements, from conceptual stage right through to the final product.</p>​
                    <p>So make that leap and let’s work together on making your idea a visual treat and a reality!​​​​​</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div id="section3" class="wrapperA"><!--Page Content-->
            <div id="home-sectionC" class="content" >
                <img src="assets/elements/home-sectionC-background.png">    

                <div id="portfolioGallery">

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="assets/images/audiobullys.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <p>Disruption Disruption Disruption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="assets/images/audiobullys.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <p>Disruption Disruption Disruption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="assets/images/audiobullys.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <p>Disruption Disruption Disruption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="assets/images/audiobullys.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <p>Disruption Disruption Disruption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="assets/images/nta2.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <p>Disruption Disruption Disruption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="assets/images/look.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <p>Disruption Disruption Disruption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="assets/images/open-bookheat.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <p>Disruption Disruption Disruption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  

        <div id="section4" id="1" class="wrapperB"><!--Page Content-->
            <div id="home-sectionD" class="content" >

                <div class="home-sectionD-textbox">
                    <h3>Reesa Amadeo Wolf: Entrepreneur MD at Fresh Young Media </h3>
                    <p>We knew Srt of the bigger vision for what we do assion for what we do assion for what we do assion for what weas a social enterprise. We will be working with Spacehopper Design for a long time!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="home-sectionD-textbox">
                    <h3>Reesa Amadeo Wolf: Entrepreneur MD at Fresh Young Media </h3>
                    <p>We knew Srt of the bigger vision for what we do assion for what we do assion for what we do assion for what weas a social enterprise. We will be working with Spacehopper Design for a long time!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="home-sectionD-textbox">
                    <h3>Reesa Amadeo Wolf: Entrepreneur MD at Fresh Young Media </h3>
                    <p>We knew Srt of the bigger vision for what we do assion for what we do assion for what we do assion for what weas a social enterprise. We will be working with Spacehopper Design for a long time!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="home-sectionD-textbox">
                    <h3>Reesa Amadeo Wolf: Entrepreneur MD at Fresh Young Media </h3>
                    <p>We knew Srt of the bigger vision for what we do assion for what we do assion for what we do assion for what weas a social enterprise. We will be working with Spacehopper Design for a long time!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="home-sectionD-textbox">
                    <h3>Reesa Amadeo Wolf: Entrepreneur MD at Fresh Young Media </h3>
                    <p>We knew Srt of the bigger vision for what we do assion for what we do assion for what we do assion for what weas a social enterprise. We will be working with Spacehopper Design for a long time!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="home-sectionD-textbox">
                    <h3>Reesa Amadeo Wolf: Entrepreneur MD at Fresh Young Media </h3>
                    <p>We knew Srt of the bigger vision for what we do assion for what we do assion for what we do assion for what weas a social enterprise. We will be working with Spacehopper Design for a long time!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="home-sectionD-textbox">
                    <h3>Reesa Amadeo Wolf: Entrepreneur MD at Fresh Young Media </h3>
                    <p>We knew Srt of the bigger vision for what we do assion for what we do assion for what we do assion for what weas a social enterprise. We will be working with Spacehopper Design for a long time!</p>
                </div>

                <img src="assets/elements/home-sectionD-background.png">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div id="section5" class="contactSectionWrapper"><!--Page Content-->
            <div id="contactSection" class="content" >

                <h2>Want to Get in Touch?</h2>              

                <div id="grid1">
                    <form id="contactForm" action="email.php" method="post">
                        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                        <input class="input" id="name" type="text" required placeholder="Enter Name">

                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input class="input" id="email" type="email" required placeholder="Enter Email">

                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="input" id="message" required></textarea>

                        <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </form>

                    <div id="contact-info">
                        <p><strong>Email:</strong> Support@LoaiDesign.co.uk</p>
                        <p><strong>Telephone:</strong> +44 0 745326 2993</p>
                        <p><strong>Skype:</strong> Loai.Bassam</p>
                    </div>
                        <br>
                    <div class="socialbar icons">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LOAI.Design.Studio" class="facebook" target="_blank"><span>Facebook</span></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/LoaiBassam" class="twitter" target="_blank"><span>Twitter</span></a>
                        <a href="http://uk.linkedin.com/in/loaibassam" class="linkedin" target="_blank"><span>Linkedin</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div id="grid2">
                    <img alt="" src="assets/elements/map.png" id="map">
                </div>      

            </div>  
        </div>

        <footer id="footer"><!--Footer Section-->
            <div id="footerContent">
                <p>Copyright ©2013 Spacehopper Design. All rights reserved.</p><a href="http://www.loaidesign.co.uk" style="padding-top: 20px;">Website Designed By<img style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle;" alt="loai design studio responsive website design" src="assets/elements/loaidesignstudio-logo.png"></a>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div><!--The End Of The Page-->    
    <!--Scripts Links-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libraries/modernizr.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

    line-height: 125%;
    text-align: center;  
    overflow-x: hidden;

    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;  
}

/*Font Face*/
@font-face { font-family: Comfortaa; src: url('Comfortaa-Light.ttf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: Comfortaa; font-weight: bold; src: url('Comfortaa-Bold.ttf');}
/*Fonts*/h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, a, ol, li, span, label, blockquote, figcaption, abbr, td, input, textarea {
    font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #636363;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

small {
    font-size: 13px;
}

strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

em {
    font-style: italic; 
}

img {
    display: block;
}


/*MAIN/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/   
/*Main Page*/#Page {    
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    margin-top: 103px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*Wrappers*/.wrapper, .wrapperA, .wrapperB, .contactSectionWrapper { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

    .wrapper {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .wrapperA {
        background-color: #F58221;
    }

    .wrapperB {
        background-color: #23408E;
    }

/*Content Container*/.content {
    width: 1030px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: auto;   
    overflow: hidden;
}


/*HEADER///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
/*Header Wrapper*/#headerWrapper {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; left: 0; 
    z-index: 1000;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/*Header Content Container*/#headerContent {
    width: 1030px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: auto;   
    overflow: auto;
}

/*Header Logo*/#headerLogo {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

/*Main Menu*/#mainMenu {
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: right;
}

    #mainMenu li {
        float: left;
    }

    #mainMenu a {
        color: #F58221;

        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-left: 5px;

        border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

        -webkit-transition: background 0.1s linear;
        -moz-transition: background 0.1s linear;
        -ms-transition: background 0.1s linear;
        -o-transition: background 0.1s linear;
        transition: background 0.1s linear;
    }

    #mainMenu a:hover {
        color: #23408E; 
    }   

    #mainMenu a.active {
        color: #7E7E7E;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        cursor: default;
    }

/*Tablet & Phone Header (Hidden From Widescreen's)*/
.secondHeader-menuButton, #secondHeader, #logo-smallScreen {
    display: none;
}



/*FOOTER////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/  
/*Footer Section*/
#footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #192E66;
    background-color: #23408E;
    width: 100%;
}

#footerContent {
    width: 1030px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;   
    overflow: hidden;
}

    #footerContent * {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 13px;
    }



/*PAGES////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/   
/*About Page*/  
#home-sectionB {
    position: relative;
}

    #home-sectionB-textbox1 {
        width: 500px;
        max-width: 100%;

        position: absolute;
        bottom: 135px;
        right: 50px;

        text-align: justify;
    }

        #home-sectionB-textbox1 p, h3 {
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }



/*Portfolio Page*/  
#home-sectionC {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

    #portfolioGallery * {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

#portfolioGallery .item {
    border: 1px dashed #FFFFFF;
    width: 310px; height: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

    #portfolioGallery .item div {
        background-color: #23408E;  
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        padding: 100px 20px 20px 20px;
    }

    #portfolioGallery .item img {
        max-width: 380px; 
    }

        #portfolioGallery .item:hover > img {
            display: none;
        }



/*Endorsements*/    
#home-sectionD {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.home-sectionD-textbox * {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.home-sectionD-textbox {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    clear: both;
}

    .home-sectionD-textbox:last-of-type {
        padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
    }

    .home-sectionD-textbox:before {
        content: url('../elements/quote.png');
        padding-right: 20px;
        float: left;
    }



/*Contact Page*/
.contactSectionWrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('../elements/strip.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

#contactSection h2 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    color: #F58221;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#grid1 {
    width: 40%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -2px;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

#grid2 {
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -2px;
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;    
}

    #contactForm label{
        color: #23408E;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #contactForm input, 
    #contactForm textarea {     
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;

        text-align: left;
        outline: none;

        border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #contactForm textarea{
        resize: vertical;
    }

    #submit{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background: #23408E;
        border: none;

        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 10px;

        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 15px;

        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }   

    #submit:hover, 
    #submit:active {
        background: #F58221;
    }   

.notSelected {
    color: #B2B2B2;
    border: 1px solid #23408E;
}

.selected {
    color: #F58221;
    border: 1px solid #F58221;
}

#contact-info {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

/*Social Media Icons*/
.socialbar {
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
}

    .icons a {
        background-image:url("../elements/socialmediaicons.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .icons a {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
    }

        .icons a span {
            display: none;
        }

    .icons a.facebook { background-position: 0 -160px; }
    .icons a.facebook:hover { background-position: 0 -200px; }

    .icons a.linkedin { background-position: 0 -720px; }
    .icons a.linkedin:hover { background-position: 0 -760px; }

    .icons a.twitter { background-position: 0 -1520px; }
    .icons a.twitter:hover { background-position: 0 -1560px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a small script that does this for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
  return string
    .replace(/^\//,'')
    .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
    .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
  var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
    if (  locationPath == thisPath
    && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
      if (target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $(this).click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
            location.hash = target;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // use the first element that is "scrollable"
  function scrollableElement(els) {
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
      var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
      if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
        return el;
      } else {
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
        var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
        if (isScrollable) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
  }

});
```

FYI, this script is taken from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

Comment: That worked like a charm thank you very much! However, How do I make the Clicked Link have a class .active? and it still cropping some of the page sections, take a look live here: http://loaistudio.com/